# Concat checkbox values into a variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to get all the values of the checkbox list and concatenate them into a single variable.

This is my HTML

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let event of testcases" >
     <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{event.upload}}" id="flexCheckDefault">
              
              {{event.name}}
              <h5 class="mb-0"> 
              </h5>
  </div>
```

I want to concatenate the **"{{event.upload}}"** I checked into a single variable. How can I do that please?

So if my list is like this

```
testcases= [
    {
      name: 'C001',
      upload: 'Photography',
      
    },
    {
      name: 'C002',
      upload: 'Writing',
      
    },
    {
      name: 'C003',
      upload: 'Painting',
      
    },
]
```

And I check the 2 first rows I want the result to be: "**Photography Writing**"

Answer (score 0):

You can get update your model to track the checked state and reduce the values to a concatenated string.

Added checked prop that is bound to a new event.checked property.

```
 <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{event.upload}}" [checked]=“event.checked” id="flexCheckDefault">
```

Update the model to look like this

```
testcases= [
{
  name: 'C001',
  upload: 'Photography',
  checked: false
},
{
  name: 'C002',
  upload: 'Writing',
  checked: false
},
{
  name: 'C003',
  upload: 'Painting',
  checked: false
},
]
```

Then have a function that concatenates the checked values, like this

```
getConcatString(testCases) {
   return testCases
     .filter(x => x.checked)
     .map(x => x.upload)
     .join(‘ ‘);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but when i add a button with a function console.log(this.getConcatString) it doesn't show anything

Comment: It sounds like your checked property in the html is not binding. If you comment out the filter() line you can confirm this if you see all strings in the concatenated string.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use the getConcatString function inside my html and where do i use it please?

Comment: You can add a an event callback to the input like this (change)=“getConcatString(testcases)”